# How to add real vocal/lyrics in a midi file? I want to assign every key a real song part

Tags: midi

A noob here. I want to assign part of a song to every key and then convert it into a midi file. Is that possible?  For example, every small part of song is a note and when it plays in a midi software, instead of only music full song is played.
no i dont want to add lyrics. i have a app similar to piano tiles and it is programmed such that it will play from midi. So now i want to play songs instead of only music. So i want to add full song maybe as notes in amidi file. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by adding real vocal lyrics. But is this what you are trying to do?

With the right software you could take a recording of a song - an mp3 for example - and split it into <=88 equal samples. Then you could assign each sample to a different note. The first sample should be assigned to the lowest note, the second to the second lowest and so on. Now, in 4/4 time, write a chromatic scale, in semibreves, from the bottom note to the top note, placing the notes on the first beat of each bar: 88 bars.

Now play it back, adjusting the tempo until it sounds right. Make sure the samples are ending crisply, with no envelopes. And make sure any variations in velocity and aftertouch aren't being applied.

Comment: no i dont want to add lyrics. i have a app similar to piano tiles and it is programmed such that it will play from midi. So now i want to play songs instead of only music. So i want to add full song maybe as notes in amidi file. how can i do it?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what Midi is. If you can, please re-write your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are  different solutions to add lyrics to music:

- Midi software
- Notation software
- Youtube adding subtitles
- Windows media player

As we don‘t recommend software you have to look up for midi player apps with karaoke options. They are also called karamidi, but not all are useful to give in th the lyrics.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid recommending software.  Questions specifically asking for recommendations are off topic, but that does not mean that an answer cannot contain a recommendation.

Comment: no i dont want to add lyrics. i have a app similar to piano tiles and it is programmed such that it will play from midi. So now i want to play songs instead of only music. So i want to add full song maybe as notes in amidi file. how can i do it?